# How to send images form an Activity to another Activity?

Tags: android

I am trying to make an App that have 2 `Activities`. `Activity1` is a gallery can call `Activity2`. `Activity2` is a camera app that capture images then send these images to `Activity1` and `Activity1` will show these images in gallery.I can't send images between two `Activities`.

This code is my gallery in `Activity1`. I know `SerializebleBitmap` but in my code how can I put it in the gallery list? Here is my code:

```
public class HelloGallery extends Activity {
private Gallery gallery;
private ImageView imgView;
private Button btn;
private static final int SHOW_SUB_FORM = 0;
private String[] imglist;
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
private Integer[] mImageIds = {
        R.drawable.sample_0,
        R.drawable.sample_1,
        R.drawable.sample_2,
        R.drawable.sample_3,
        R.drawable.sample_4,
        R.drawable.sample_5,
        R.drawable.sample_6,
        R.drawable.sample_7
};
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
  gallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery);
    gallery.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
   imgView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView01); 
    imgView.setImageResource(mImageIds[0]);

    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Takept);


       btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){




        public void onClick(View v) {

            btn_onClick();
        }

    }); 



    if (extras != null){

        String[] imglist= extras.getStringArray("IMAGE_LIST");
        imgView.setImageResource(mImageIds[0]);


    }

    gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(HelloGallery.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            imgView.setImageResource(mImageIds[position]);




        }
    });


};

private void btn_onClick() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(HelloGallery.this,CameraDemo.class);


    startActivity(intent);
} 

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    int mGalleryItemBackground;
    private Context mContext;


    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
        TypedArray attr = mContext.obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.HelloGallery);
        mGalleryItemBackground = attr.getResourceId(
                R.styleable.HelloGallery_android_galleryItemBackground, 0);
        attr.recycle();
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mImageIds.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);

        imageView.setImageResource(mImageIds[position]);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(100, 100));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        imageView.setBackgroundResource(mGalleryItemBackground);

        return imageView;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4497813/how-to-communicate-two-android-applications

Comment: here convert image to bitmap and pass it to another activity 
[use this answer][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17879210/2377760

Answer (score 0):

In general, you dont want to be sending an image from one activity to another. You will want activity 1 to store it somewhere, and then tell activity 2 to go and access it. Possibly in another base application class that both activities can access.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

In your intent, your have possibility to pass Serializable objects.

Do to, you must create a class for serilizing/deserializing your image like this:

```
    import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.Serializable;

    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat;

    public class SerializableBitmap implements Serializable {
       private static final long serialVersionUID = 1208813848065674061L;
       private Bitmap bitmap;
       // Serialize image
       private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException {
          ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
          bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos); 
          byte[] bitmapdata = bos.toByteArray();
          out.write(bitmapdata, 0, bitmapdata.length);
       }

       // Deserialize image
       private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
           ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
           int b;
           while((b = in.read()) != -1)
              byteStream.write(b);
           byte bitmapBytes[] = byteStream.toByteArray();
           bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bitmapBytes, 0, bitmapBytes.length);
       }

       public Bitmap getBitmap() {
          return bitmap;
       }

       public void setBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
          this.bitmap = bitmap;
       }
   }
```

Fill free to use setBitmap() and getBitmap() methods to serialize/deserilize your bitmap, and in your intent put the serializable bitmap object:

```
    intent.putExtra(extraDataKey, serializableBitmap);
```

But consider that this solution could cause performance problems if the image is too large.

Hope it help.

Comment: [Bitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html) has already implemented [Parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html), directly pass bitmap to intent.putExtra(), do not need wrap it once more.

Comment: And then how can I show these images on galleyry in activity1?

Comment: @user1063009 Bitmap image = (Bitmap) getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable(extraDataKey);

Comment: Yes, it could work. But I confirm that the solution with SerializableBitmap worked fine for me. I'll try if Parcelable can do the job. Tkank you.

Comment: @user1063009: if you have an ImageView then you can do as this: imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

Comment: Thank you. But I just want take images to gallery list, then I click on the item on gallery it will show in Imageview. Do you understand me? Wow, so complex :))

Answer (score 0):

you send the location of the image like "R.drawable.sample_0" you send it as string and then when you get it in activity 2, you reach it from your drawables . that's all no need to send the image :)