# Set image from gridview to another activity

Tags: android, textview

I am creating an application for see and share image but,i don't know How to set selected image from gridview to SingleActivity that have a imageview.
Please help me.
any help will be appreciate.

My full code is given below.

**MainActivity.java**

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    customGridAdapter = new GridViewAdapter(this, R.layout.row_grid, getData());
    gridView.setAdapter(customGridAdapter);

    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {
            Intent i = 
                      new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleViewActivity.class);
                      // Pass image index
                      i.putExtra("id", position);
                      startActivity(i);
        }

    });

}

private ArrayList<ImageItem> getData() {
    final ArrayList<ImageItem> imageItems = new ArrayList<ImageItem>();
    // retrieve String drawable array
    TypedArray imgs = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.image_ids);
    for (int i = 0; i < imgs.length(); i++) {
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),
                imgs.getResourceId(i, -1));
        imageItems.add(new ImageItem(bitmap, "Image#" + i));
    }

    return imageItems;

}
```

**GridViewAdapter.java**

```
    public GridViewAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId,
        ArrayList<ImageItem> data) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder = null;

    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.imageTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.text);
        holder.image = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.image);
        row.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
    }

    ImageItem item = data.get(position);
    holder.imageTitle.setText(item.getTitle());
    holder.image.setImageBitmap(item.getImage());
    return row;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView imageTitle;
    ImageView image;
}
```

**SingleViewActivity.java**

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.single_view);

    Intent i = getIntent();

    // Selected image id
    int position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");
    ImageViewPic = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.SingleView);
    }
```

**Arrays.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<string-array name="image_ids">
    <item>@drawable/image_1</item>
    <item>@drawable/image_2</item>
    <item>@drawable/image_3</item>
    <item>@drawable/image_4</item>
    <item>@drawable/image_5</item>
    <item>@drawable/image_6</item>
    <item>@drawable/image_7</item>
    <item>@drawable/image_8</item>
    <item>@drawable/image_9</item>
    <item>@drawable/image_1</item>
    <item>@drawable/image_2</item>
    <item>@drawable/image_3</item>
    <item>@drawable/image_4</item>
    <item>@drawable/image_5</item>
    <item>@drawable/image_6</item>
    <item>@drawable/image_7</item>
    <item>@drawable/image_8</item>
    <item>@drawable/image_9</item>
</string-array>
```

**row_grid.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="5dp" 
android:clickable="false"
android:background="@drawable/grid_color_selector"
android:focusable="true">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp" >
</ImageView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="12sp" >
</TextView>
```

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17878907/get-imageviews-image-and-send-it-to-an-activity-with-intent)

Comment: how can i set image to imageview of singleviewActivity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Intent i = getIntent(); 
int position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");
ImageViewPic = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.SingleView);
getData().get(position);
ImageItem item = getData().get(position); 
ImageViewPic .setImageBitmap(item.getImage());

 private ArrayList<ImageItem> getData() {
final ArrayList<ImageItem> imageItems = new ArrayList<ImageItem>();
// retrieve String drawable array
TypedArray imgs = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.image_ids);
for (int i = 0; i < imgs.length(); i++) {
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),
            imgs.getResourceId(i, -1));
    imageItems.add(new ImageItem(bitmap, "Image#" + i));
}

return imageItems;

 }
```

Comment: in data we r geating nullpinnterexpection

Comment: Thanks for response deepak.but my image is not clickable even i set "android:clickable=true" in row_grid.xml file.

Comment: holder.image.setonclicklistenser(){}

do this

Comment: i try this,but i am getting error on startActivity(intent) method like"The method startActivity(Intent) is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){}".

Comment: Thanks for answer to all of you.i am getting the correct solution for it.