# how to send data using bundle inside RecyclerView onclick method

Tags: android

i want to send my name and image in recycler view oclick but i m bit confused should i use paraceble or simple bundle mechanism how to i send and recived it

```
public class FamousPeople

{
private static final String FAMOUS_NAME = "famous name";
private static final String FAMOUS_PHOTO="photo";
private String name;
private int photo;
private String details;

FamousPeople(String name, int photo) {

    this.name = name;
    this.photo = photo;
}
public  FamousPeople(){


}


public String getDetails() {
    return details;
}

public void setDetails(String details) {
    this.details = details;
}

public int getPhoto() {
    return photo;
}

public void setPhoto(int photo) {
    this.photo = photo;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}


   }
```

BiographyViewHolder class in which i have to pass my images and text data

```
 class BiographyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
       implements View.OnClickListener {

   public TextView textView;
  public ImageView imageView;
List<FamousPeople> famousPeoples=GetData.getListdata();


public BiographyViewHolder(View itemView)
{
    super(itemView);
    itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    textView= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.country_name);
    imageView= (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.country_photo);


}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent  intent=new Intent();
    Bundle bundle=new Bundle();

    intent.putExtras(bundle);
    view.getContext().startActivity(intent);

}

 }
```

GetData class getting data from this class

```
     public  class GetData {
    public static List<FamousPeople> getListdata() {
    List<FamousPeople> famousPeoples = new ArrayList<>();
    famousPeoples.add(new FamousPeople("rahul", R.drawable.amitabh));
    famousPeoples.add(new FamousPeople("sumit", R.drawable.cvraman));
    famousPeoples.add(new FamousPeople("neha", R.drawable.indira));
    famousPeoples.add(new FamousPeople("surbhi", R.drawable.kishorkumar));
    famousPeoples.add(new FamousPeople("rahul", R.drawable.modi));
    famousPeoples.add(new FamousPeople("sumit", R.drawable.mother));
    famousPeoples.add(new FamousPeople("neha", R.drawable.nehru)) 

    return famousPeoples;
}
```

Comment: both of paraceble / serializable  or simple bundle mechanism are fine in your case

Comment: but serialization is slower in performance compare to paraceble and i m going to use xml pull parser to get the data ,so m bit confused when to use paraceble and when to use simple bundle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to edit your `onClick()` function as below.
All you need is get data from your list, pointed by `getAdapterPosition` and then pass them to `bundle`

```
    @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent  intent=new Intent();
            Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
            bundle.putInt("IMAGE", famousPeoples.get(getAdapterPosition()).getPhoto());
            bundle.putString("NAME", famousPeoples.get(getAdapterPosition()).getName());
intent.putExtras(bundle);
    view.getContext().startActivity(intent);

}
```

Comment: i m getting the name but not receiving the images ,

Comment: see i added in the answer column

Comment: try to use setImageDrawable() instead of setImageResource().
Also should print some log to get the passed values and received values

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail, container, false);
   textView= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.bioname);
    imageView= (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    Bundle getBundle = null;
    getBundle = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();

    String name = getBundle.getString("NAME");
    int id = getBundle.getInt("IMAGE");
    textView.setText(name);
    imageView.setImageResource(id);
    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get image and name , you have to do something like this,

For ex : **YOUR CLICK EVENT** to send data onClick();

```
ViewHolder VHheaderItem = (ViewHolder) view;

    VHheaderItem.image_detail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            Intent i = new Intent(CurrentClass.this, AnotherClass.class);
                            i.putExtra("Name", listItems1.get(position).getVarName(););
                            startActivity(i);
                        }
                    });
```

To receive it ,

```
String drName = getIntent().getStringExtra("Name");
```

Now if you want to pass image through intent then

```
imageView.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap image= imageView.getDrawingCache();

Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putParcelable("imagebitmap", image);
intent.putExtras(extras);
startActivity(intent);
```

To receive it,

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap) extras.getParcelable("imagebitmap");

image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Go through [get ImageView's image and send it to an activity with Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17878907/get-imageviews-image-and-send-it-to-an-activity-with-intent) for more detail and [how to pass images through intent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23577964/2826147)

Comment: no its not working i debug the area where activity receiving the images ,images are coming to the variable but not displaying it that is problem

Comment: if you are using private int photo; for photo than pass int in intent. if you are getting that value @rahulvyas then set that image.

Comment: what i m saying is that the id of the picture is coming when i start the debug session but picture is not displaying on imageview

Comment: problem solved as i was doing mistake in xml image view

Comment: yes , you have taken image in int as written in my answer so you were unable to get that. @rahulvyas