# Passing View with Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, view

I want to passing my `view`to update my `view` in other activity. This is my code to passing `view`.

```
emp_photo_edit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                i.putExtra("container", (Serializable) viewDialog);
                ((EmployeeActivity)context).startActivityForResult(i, 2017);
            }
        });
```

Then i want to update my view in other activity

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 2017 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();
        View apa = (View) data.getSerializableExtra("content");
        //View dialog = View.inflate(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.dialog_employee_edit,null);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) apa.findViewById(R.id.emp_photo_edit);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
    }
}
```

But it show Exception.

```
  FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
  java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to java.io.Serializable
    at com.fingerspot.hz07.revocloud.adapter.EmployeeAdapter$MyViewHolder$5.onClick(EmployeeAdapter.java:334)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Views cannot be passed from one `Activity` to another.

Answer (score 3):

Arguments passed to the bundle should implement the `Serializable` or `Parcelable` interface. The `LinearLayout` doesn't. The best solution is to pass the data inside the view to the Intent and apply that to a view in the receiving `Activity`

Comment: but, i want to update that view in another activity, can i do that?

Comment: Yes, you should pass the attributes you need and apply them to the view in the other Activity

Comment: i have imageview that i should update in another activity, how to do that?

Comment: @Huzain: "i have imageview that i should update in another activity, how to do that?" -- you don't. That is akin to saying "I have a Web page that I should update in another Web page". One Web page does not directly modify the HTML of another Web page. Instead, one Web page updates some shared state (e.g., on the server) that is used by the other Web page. The same thing holds here: you update some state from one activity that the other activity uses when it returns to the foreground.

Answer (score 1):

You can not pass a view (imageview) in intent.

You should pass image bitmap as `ByteArray` or `Parcelable` in intent like below.

**Pass bitmap as ByteArray:**

First Convert image into `ByteArray` and then pass into Intent and in next activity get `ByteArray` from `Bundle` and convert into image(Bitmap) and set into `ImageView`.

Convert `Bitmap` to `ByteArray` and pass into `Intent`:-

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

Intent intent = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("picture", byteArray);
startActivity(intent);
```

Get `ByteArray` from `Bundle` and convert into `Bitmap` image:-

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
byte[] byteArray = extras.getByteArray("picture");

Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

**OR**

**Pass bitmap as Parcelable:**

Pass `Bitmap` directly into Intent as `Parcelable` extra and get bitmap as `Parcelable` extra in next activity from `Bundle`, but the problem is if your Bitmap/Image size is big at that time the image is not load in next activity.

Checkout
[get ImageView's image and send it to an activity with Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17878907/get-imageviews-image-and-send-it-to-an-activity-with-intent?answertab=votes#tab-top)